# Facebook login using xamarin ios C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, facebook-login

I am working on iOS app using xamarin C# and trying to implement facebook login. I am having a hard time figuring out how to go with it. Any kind of leads will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This kind of question is well suited for documentation, but poorly suited for a Q&A site. Please have a look at the [Help Centre to know what we consider to be good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Very vague question, but the answer is simple enough.

1. Download [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk) component into your project.
2. Register and get your app ID from [Facebook Developer Site](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
3. Get your user token using your login and continue with your work.

Follow the [getting started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebook-sdk) code to learn how to use the component.

I hope this helps.